# Get last occurence of nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

By querying two classes and applying the following methods:

```
.each_with_index.chunk { |enum, i| enum.is_a?(Note) }
```

I get this structure:

```
[
  [false, [[#<Post id: 1, title: "something", 0]]],
  [false, [[#<Post id: 2, title: "something", 1], [#<Post id: 3, title: "something", 2]]],
  [true, [[#<Note id: 1, title: "something", 3], [#<Note id: 77, title: "something", 4]]]
]
```

In the view I need to know when I'm on the last object, in this case index position 4, how do I do this?

Comment: You can also iterate through it with `each_with_index`.

Comment: This far I've done `.each {|enum, arr|}` in the view. How would I structure the parameters such that it includes the third parameter `index` as well?

Comment: @Numbers : What you get by `.each_with_index.chunk { |enum, i| enum.is_a?(Note) }` without using `.to_a`  at the end

Comment: What if you `pop` the last element of the array? (`pop` removes the last element of an Array)

Comment: should there be a comma after `[#<Post id: 3, title: "something", 2]]]` ?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: @GaganGami It doesn't alter anything, so now removed.

Comment: `chunk` should produce an array of arrays whose first elements alternate between `true` and `false`, but your first two elements both have `false`. Did you omit some elements from the output you show?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Honestly I replicated my code and data for clarity reasons, so perhaps something could very well be incorrect. The solution I went with eventually though, was omitting the `with_index` preceding `.chunk` and applied it on the iterator in the view instead as suggested by the choosen answer.

Comment: Considering the answer you checkmarked, it appears you simply want the last element of the array on the left side of `=` above (call it `a`), or the last element of that array that is an instance of `Note`. If so, I don't see the point of `chunk`ing.  Why not just `a.last` or `a.reverse.find { |instance| instance.class == Note }`? (I don't know Rails, so perhaps I'm missing something.) `instance.class == Note` could alternatively be written `instance.is_a?(Note)` or `Note === instance`.

Comment: Originally I wanted the index of each object in the collection, but no one understood this or knew how to do it, so I went with the solution provided in my last comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you could just do:

```
array.flatten.last
```

Which looks like this:

```
[1] pry(main)> [[false, [["1"]]], [false, [["2"], ["post 3"]]], [true, [["1"], ["note 77"]]]].flatten.last
=> "note 77"
```

Thanks Cary for the revision.

Comment: That would give a collection size of 3, when I'm looking for 5. (The naming of your parameters should be inversed.)